# Filter a json from another json in javascript (no jQuery)

Tags: json

i have a json data generated from a vip and has many fields, i want to filter out the data of the fields that is only needed.
The json like this:

```
mycontacts=
 [
    {
        "owner": "swapneil",
        "fleet_name": "RancorService",
        "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
        "environment": "RancorService/JP",
        "vip_port": 80,
        "partition": "YES",
        "protocol": "HTTP",
        "monitor": "Consistent (http-ping)",
        "lbset": "Consistent",
        "predictor": "Consistent",
        "spillover": "Consistent",
        "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
        "max_conns": "Consistent : (36)",
        "vip_cipher": null,
        "vip_cip": "Consistent",
        "vip_tier": "Consistent(Tier1)",
        "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
        "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
        "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
        "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
        "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
        "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
        "server_port": "Consistent",
        "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
        "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
        "persistent_method": "Consistent",
        "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"
    },
    {
        "owner": "swapneil",
        "fleet_name": "RancorService",
        "creation_date": "09-03-2020",
        "environment": "RancorService/JP",
        "vip_port": 443,
        "partition": "YES",
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "monitor": "Consistent (ssl-ping)",
        "lbset": "NC (>1 Vip's in same LB)",
        "predictor": "NC (leastconns,ROUNDROBINSHOULD BE ROUNDROBIN)",
        "spillover": "Consistent",
        "vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)",
        "max_conns": "Consistent : (9000)",
        "vip_cipher": null,
        "vip_cip": "Consistent",
        "vip_tier": "Consistent(Non-Tier1)",
        "vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)",
        "vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)",
        "vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)",
        "vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)",
        "down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)",
        "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)",
        "server_port": "Consistent",
        "vip_server_timeout": "Consistent",
        "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent",
        "persistent_method": "Consistent",
        "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"
    }
]
```

I want to filter out these fields from this json :
The result should be a json have fields and values of only those fields mentioned below.

```
{
    "fleet_name",
    "environment",
    "vip_port",
    "protocol",
    "lbset",
    "predictor",
    "spillover",
    "vip_cipher",
    "vip_cip",
    "vip_tier",
    "vip_siloed",
    "vip_globalized",
    "vip_dedicated",
    "vip_retail_tag",
    "down_stat_flush",
    "vip_type",
    "vip_client_timeout"
}
```

How to do that in javascript??

I want the data of only those fields that are mentioned above and leave the rest.

Comment: Is your desired output like `[{"fleet_name": "RancorService", "environment": "RancorService/JP", [...] "vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)", "vip_client_timeout": "Consistent"}]` or like `[{"owner": "swapneil", "creation_date": "09-03-2020", [...] "persistent_method": "Consistent", "persistent_timeout": "Consistent"}]` or something different?

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: pls see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for formatting your posts

Comment: @Mr.Yeah like the second option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this ?

```js
var src = [{"owner": "swapneil","fleet_name": "RancorService","creation_date": "09-03-2020","environment": "RancorService/JP","vip_port": 80,"partition": "YES","protocol": "HTTP","monitor": "Consistent (http-ping)","lbset": "Consistent","predictor": "Consistent","spillover": "Consistent","vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)","max_conns": "Consistent : (36)","vip_cipher": null,"vip_cip": "Consistent","vip_tier": "Consistent(Tier1)","vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)","vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)","vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)","vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)","down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)","vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)","server_port": "Consistent","vip_server_timeout": "Consistent","vip_client_timeout": "Consistent","persistent_method": "Consistent","persistent_timeout": "Consistent"},{"owner": "swapneil","fleet_name": "RancorService","creation_date": "09-03-2020","environment": "RancorService/JP","vip_port": 443,"partition": "YES","protocol": "TCP","monitor": "Consistent (ssl-ping)","lbset": "NC (>1 Vip's in same LB)","predictor": "NC (leastconns,ROUNDROBINSHOULD BE ROUNDROBIN)","spillover": "Consistent","vip_cka": "Consistent :(NO)","max_conns": "Consistent : (9000)","vip_cipher": null,"vip_cip": "Consistent","vip_tier": "Consistent(Non-Tier1)","vip_siloed": "Consistent(Non-SILOED)","vip_globalized": "Consistent(Non-GLOBALIZED)","vip_dedicated": "Consistent(Non-DEDICATED_VIP)","vip_retail_tag": "Consistent(RETAIL_TAG)","down_stat_flush": "Consistent :(ENABLED)","vip_type": "Consistent (BACKEND)","server_port": "Consistent","vip_server_timeout": "Consistent","vip_client_timeout": "Consistent","persistent_method": "Consistent","persistent_timeout": "Consistent"}];
var fields = ["fleet_name","environment","vip_port","protocol","lbset","predictor","spillover","vip_cipher","vip_cip","vip_tier","vip_siloed","vip_globalized","vip_dedicated","vip_retail_tag","down_stat_flush","vip_type","vip_client_timeout"];
var res = [];
for(var l1 in src) {
    var res2 = {};
    for(var l2 in src[l1]) {
        if (fields.indexOf(l2) > -1) {
            res2[l2] = src[l1][l2];
        }
    }
    res.push(res2);
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(res,null,1));
```